# Variable check wrong code (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var old;
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
        old = document.getElementById('load_donnees3').innerHTML;
        $('#load_donnees3').load('shoutbox-number.php').fadeIn("slow");
        if (old != document.getElementById('load_donnees3').innerHTML) {
            var audio = new Audio('bip.mp3');
            audio.play();
        }
    }, 200); 
</script>
```

The `shoutbox-number.php` page return a number, when I change the number of the page, the var `old` is changed at the same time than the div `load_donnees3`, why?
I wan't to view if the code in the div change, if it change, the sound `bip.mp3` is played.

Comment: You do not need to compare the entire DOM-element. If the `shoutbox-number.php` returns one (random?) number, store it in one variable and just check its value. And a tip: You should use about 2 secs to test it this way... with just 200 miliseconds I doubt you will see something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a value:

```
old = document.getElementById('load_donnees3').innerHTML;
```

Then comparing it to... *the same value*:

```
if (old != document.getElementById('load_donnees3').innerHTML)
```

That `if` statement will *always* be `false`, since a value is never `!=` itself.

If this code is meant to change the source of the value:

```
$('#load_donnees3').load('shoutbox-number.php').fadeIn("slow");
```

Then you're going to want to get the new value *after* this executes.  Since this executes asynchronously, your comparison will need to happen in the callback function.  Something like this:

```
$('#load_donnees3').load('shoutbox-number.php', function () {
    $('#load_donnees3').fadeIn("slow");
    if (old != document.getElementById('load_donnees3').innerHTML) {
        var audio = new Audio('bip.mp3');
        audio.play();
    }
});
```